# Dependency between repositories

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository, domain-driven-design

I'm using Entity Framework with DDD.

I have the following entities: Person, Customer, Employee

Person is abstract.
Customer and Employee inherit person.
Person has references to the Person Address (List).

Should I have a repository for each type or only for each concrete type? (Just Customer and Employee)

Could I have a repository Person then Customer and Employee repositories depend on it internally to avoid redundant code? (Using DI by constructor injection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't meant to give a complete application structure, but a good basis for designing what you may need when working with different Repositories and Inheritance etc.

```
// Model stuff...
public interface IBaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseEntity : IBaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    // Add some extra fields for all Models that use BaseEntity
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    [Display(Name = "Last Modified")]
    public virtual DateTime LastModified { get; set; }

    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    [Timestamp]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public virtual byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
}

public class Person : BaseEntity
{
    // Person Model here...
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    // Extra Employee Model items here
}

public class Customer : Person
{
    // Extra Customer Model items here
}
// End Model stuff

// Repository stuff...
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();
    T GetById(int? id);
    T Add(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void Delete(int id);
    void Commit(); // To save changes rather than performing a save after each Add/Update/Delete etc.
}

public class EFRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IBaseEntity
{
    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return DbSet.AsQueryable<T>();
    }

    public virtual T GetById(int? id)
    {
        var item = DbSet.Find(id);
        return item;
    }

    public virtual T Add(T entity)
    {
        DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
        if (dbEntityEntry.State != EntityState.Detached)
        {
            dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Added;
        }
        else
        {
            DbSet.Add(entity);
        }
        // SaveChanges() - removed from each DbSet, so can call on all changes in one transaction.
        // Using Unit Of Work Pattern. Can still use it here though if wished.
        return entity;
    }
    // And so on for each storage method.
}

public interface IEmployeeRepository: IRepository<Employee>
public interface ICustomerRepository: IRepository<Customer>

public class EmployeeRepository : EFRepository<Employee>, IEmployeeRepository
public class CustomerRepository : EFRepository<Customer>, ICustomerRepository
// End Repository stuff
```

Basically you can add new Models and their Repositories by declaring the interfaces and classes with virtually nothing inside them. Everything inherits from the base crud functionality etc.
You only need to add new methods for getting records from the database in special cases for the Model being added - FindEmployeeByHairColor(color) for example, all other EF Gets, Finds etc. are the same regardless of the type.

This can get very deep, using Services to provide access to the core methods in the Repositories, add the Unit Of Work pattern to combine several DbSets into one transaction, and so on.

But using this type of layout allows me to inject into each layer the particular Repository/Service I wish to use, and keeps all logic in a single class that is re-used throughout everything that uses similar logic.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would just have repositories for Customer and Employee.

If there is shared logic between these encapsulate it in an abstract base class and have the repositories inherit from it.

So you would end up with this sort of structure:

```
public interface ICustomerRepo { }

public interface IEmployeeRepo {  }

public abstract class PersonRepoBase<T> {  }

public class CustomerRepo : PersonRepoBase<Customer>, ICustomerRepo { }

public class EmployeeRepo : PersonRepoBase<Employee>, IEmployeeRepo { }
```